# NSXMLParser won't call foundDeclerationName

Tags: objective-c, attributes, call, nsxmlparser

I have this weird problem-
I'm parsing an xml with a data fetched from the internet. The data is an xml file, I have printed it to check so I know it's legit.

I have a couple of elements, each containing 1 attribute, and there's content as well.
The parser calls DidSartElement, and it detects the element - The attribute is indeed inside the attributeDict parameter of the method. But, for some reason, foundAttributeDecleration won't get called.

Is there any knows reason this could happen for, or a way to fix this?
Tnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
foundAttributeDeclarationWithName:(NSString *)attributeName
                       forElement:(NSString *)elementName
                             type:(NSString *)type
                     defaultValue:(NSString *)defaultValue
```

isn't called for handling element attributes, it gets called only when the parser proceeds with the DTD and find attributes declaration.

To retrieve attributes for an element, use the `attributeDict` parameter.

Comment: are you 100% sure? becaues on other occasions I have uesd NSXMLParser, It did work as I excpected, and not the way you mentioned.

Comment: @Niv - yes, this method is registered under 'Handling the DTD' tasks section in [NSXMLParserDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and the method discussion doesn't correspond to the behaviour you describe.

Comment: @Niv - you are welcome ;) don't forget to read about SO Q&A process in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: But, could I know the line number and column number of specific attribute.

Comment: The problem with attributeDict is that it the attribute order seems to be non-deterministic… (AFAICT they're in hashtag order?) The reason that this is an issue is that you can't just text diff before/after XML for testing…